# Selenium is showing element not found exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am able to do validation on first page using selenium. But when i am transferring to next page than it is showing above error.

Code is:-

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        String baseUrl = "http://192.168.1.47";
        Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        selenium.open("http://192.168.1.47");
       selenium.type("username","clnt123822");
        selenium.type("birthday", "150347");
        String name = driver.findElement(By.name("username")).getAttribute("value").toString();
        String dob = driver.findElement(By.name("birthday")).getAttribute("value").toString();
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(dob);
        selenium.click("btnsubmit");
   // After pressing this button it is going to next page where i am having select
html tag.At this point error is coming
```

Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Element select1 not found

This is second page checking which is throwing error

```
selenium.type("select1","r");

            String select1 = driver.findElement(By.id("sel1")).getAttribute("value").toString();

            System.out.println(select1);
```

Comment: My cristal ball tells me it's because it can't find the element... ;-) Please provides more details about the page in question (html chunk would be best ) otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: You are using **both** WebDriver *and* **WebDriverBackedSelenium**. This isn't going to help. Drop one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to wait until the element in the second page to be visible/clickable. Try this code just after hitting the submit button in page one.

```
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(Driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("sel1")));
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have resolved the issue using below code

Comment: driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);